# Same query completes in 10 secs on SQL Server/Postgres but still going after 30 mins on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, postgresql, query-optimization

I'm trying to understand why there is such a big performance difference between the two.  This is the query that I run on both with no changes...

```
SELECT fs.person1, fs.person2, ls.artist
FROM friends AS fs
LEFT JOIN likes AS ls
ON fs.person2 = ls.person
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(select * from likes where fs.person1 = person and ls.artist = artist)
```

Both have the same data.  It's one thing if it took 2-3 times as long but from 10 seconds to over 30 mins...it's perplexing.

Data in each table...

likes = 3 INT columns and 750,000 rows

friends = 2 INT columns and 150,000 rows

Comment: The problem is with your mysql installation for sure.

Comment: I'll try installing mysql locally to see if that helps

Comment: how much data do you have in each table? provide more info so someone may figure it out.

Comment: I've added info

Comment: So the query should run in less than a second. you may have misconfiguration in your mysql i.e memory limit... Additionally you may not indexed columns correctly.

Comment: I haven't indexed columns in either.  Would SQL Server automatically create them?  I import csv files through the file import tool in SQL Server.  In mysql I do it via CREATE / LOAD

Comment: I checked SQL Management Studio - don't see any indices for the tables.

Comment: I don't think SQL server automatically index table, but there may be some differences between handling non-indexed tables. Any way you should alway index your tables. Try EXPLAIN your query to find out the problem. Beside this, i think you have memory limit on mysql server which cause mysql using Virtual memory which is a big performance issue.

Comment: ok thank you!  I'll give it a loko

Comment: I installed MySQL locally (where I have SQL Server also installed) - just as slow.  And any action takes way too much time - like alter table primary key or creating index.  I even tried the same data/query on Postgres and no problems there.

Comment: @cpd1, SQL Server will not automatically create indexes (except for table spools in plans). All other things being equal, SQL Server and PostgreSQL seem to do a better job of optimizing this query without them. All relational tables should have at least primary keys and usually indexes on foreign key columns. If you care about performance. learn about indexes. Each of these databases implement indexes differently, though.

Comment: Thank you Dan!  I'm actually reading about performance.  It just didn't occur to me that MySQL would need indexes where the other two didn't.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for MySQL and the equivalent for the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guessed at your table definition and tested with EXPLAIN to see how the optimizer would treat it.

By the way, when asking for query optimization help, always run `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and include the output, so we can see the table definition, your indexes, data types, constraints. Also run `EXPLAIN` for the query and show that.

Here's what I get for the query when I use EXPLAIN:

```
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | fs    | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | ls    | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | likes | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                                        |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

A couple of red flags appear in that EXPLAIN report.

- First, that fact that you have no indexes makes all three table references do table-scans (**type: ALL**). Since MySQL only does nested-loop joins, this means you query will have to do 150,000 x 750,000 x 750,000 row reads. No wonder it takes 30 minutes.
- Second is the note about "using join buffer (Block Nested loop)" which is saying it has to evaluate the join in batches because there's no index in which to do more targeted lookups.

Create an index:

```
ALTER TABLE likes ADD INDEX (person, artist);
```

Then the EXPLAIN looks better:

```
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+--------+---------+--------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref                            | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+--------+---------+--------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | fs    | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL   | NULL    | NULL                           |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                     |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | ls    | NULL       | ref  | person        | person | 5       | test.fs.person2                |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | likes | NULL       | ref  | person        | person | 10      | test.fs.person1,test.ls.artist |    1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+--------+---------+--------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
```

This eliminates two of the table-scans and the use of the join buffer.

But it still leaves another red flag: the DEPENDENT SUBQUERY. In general, MySQL runs dependent subqueries inefficiently, executing them once for each row of the outer query. So you're going to be executing the subquery thousands of times, even with the index lookup to help.

I use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to implement anti-joins in MySQL. There's a thorough explanation here: https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

```
SELECT fs.person1, fs.person2, ls1.artist
FROM friends AS fs
JOIN likes AS ls1
  ON fs.person2 = ls1.person
LEFT OUTER JOIN likes AS ls2
  ON fs.person1 = ls2.person AND ls1.artist = ls2.artist
WHERE ls2.person IS NULL;
```

Here's the EXPLAIN:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+--------+---------+---------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref                             | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+--------+---------+---------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | fs    | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL   | NULL    | NULL                            |    1 |   100.00 | Using where              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ls1   | NULL       | ref  | person        | person | 5       | test.fs.person2                 |    1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ls2   | NULL       | ref  | person        | person | 10      | test.fs.person1,test.ls1.artist |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+--------+---------+---------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
```

No more subquery at all, and the anti-join is resolved using a simple join with indexed lookups.

This should run much faster, assuming your indexes fit in the memory allocated for the buffer pool.

> And any action takes way too much time - like alter table primary key or creating index.

This makes me think you have not done any configuration of MySQL with respect to memory allocation. You probably have the default buffer pool size (128MB). This is something you should set relative to the available memory on your system. See https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/06/02/80-ram-tune-innodb_buffer_pool_size/

You may also like to read https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/10/12/mysql-5-7-performance-tuning-immediately-after-installation/

From what I've [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options), Microsoft SQL Server automatically resizes its buffer pool and other memory from time to time, so it's not necessary to tune it manually.

Learning to tune configuration options is necessary on MySQL. They choose default tuning settings to help ensure MySQL can run on modest servers, because it wouldn't be very friendly for it to allocate 100GB of your server RAM by default, if you don't have that much physical memory, because it would cause swapping or crashing.

There has been some talk of making MySQL tune itself dynamically, but it's a very complex task. Maybe you don't *want* MySQL to use all the memory available on your system, because you run other processes too. It's hard to guess at the right automatic tuning values for everyone's server, and doing so might encourage people to avoid learning how to allocate and monitor their own system resources.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed post!   I'm actually used to working on Sybase IQ and SQL Server so I was a bit confused on MySQL.  Only reason I'm using it was because it was a suggested database for a project.  I didn't configure anything in MySQL when I installed locally besides timeouts as I noticed fairly quickly the 30 second time limit.  The remote instance isn't fairing any better either, though.

Comment: As for indexes, you're right.  The query executed in 30 seconds after adding them.  SQL Server was still faster but MySQL did finish in reasonable amount of time after adding the indexes.  Just seemed odd that neither Postgres or SQL Server needed them.

Comment: Every database has a learning curve if you want to optimize any given query. Some databases implement automatic optimizations for certain types of queries. Good luck! I suggest you subscribe to the Percona blog, it's the best resource of expert advice on MySQL.